# Swift: How to link UITableView to individual UIDetailView Pages

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uiviewcontroller, segue

At present I have a table view with a list of universities. Upon tapping on one of these I would like to display information about these universities. My tableview cells have style: subtitle.

My tableview data source is:

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return schools.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
    -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SchoolCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
            as UITableViewCell

        let school = schools[indexPath.row] as Schools
        cell.textLabel?.text = school.university
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = school.name
        return cell
}
```

The schools.swift page:

```
class Schools: NSObject {
var university: String
var name: String


init(university: String, name: String) {
    self.university = university
    self.name = name
    super.init()
}
}
```

The sample data page:

```
let schoolsData = [ Schools(university: "Aberdeen", name: "School of Medicine")
//and so on for each university
```

I have been trying for hours to link these pages using segues. I have created the link between the tableviewcell and the view controller on the storyboard by ctrl-click dragging, but I'm stuck with the code part (prepare for segue) on my SchoolsViewTableController (table view) and my SchoolViewController.

I would like the detail page to display the "university" (for example Aberdeen) as the title.

Any help would be greatly appreciated - I am relatively new to swift so please understand my inexperience!

Thanks

Ed

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you simply need to make the connection between a user *selecting* a cell and then doing the segue to the detail view controller.

To implement that, you need to implement the UITableViewDelegate method:

[`optional func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:)

(the documentation for which I linked for you).

And in that method you would programmatically call your segue. For example, something like [`self.performSegueWithIdentifier("LetsGoToDetailView", sender: self)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:)

Comment: Thanks very much for taking the time to reply. Sorry, still slightly confused - where do I put this code? I tried in the UITableViewDelegate in the SchoolsTableViewController but no luck.

Comment: I'd suggest putting it into the same object that serves as your table view data source.  Also, make sure you have the table view delegate set to the same object as the data source.

Comment: I've put it in the SampleData.swift file, but I get 2 error messages:
- extraneous '_' in parameter: 'tableView' has no keyword argument name
- use of undeclared type 'UITableView'

This might be because I might not have the table view delegate set to the same object as the data source. How do I check this?

Comment: Check to see how and where you connected your table view to the data source.  If programmatically, you can also assign the delegate at the same time.  If in your storyboard, you can connect the delegate of your table view to the same object that the data source is connected to.

Comment: I've checked via storyboard and the outlets for both delegates and data source are the Schools Table View Controller. So, i tried to put this in:
   optional func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)

But I'm still not sure where exactly it goes (I've tried a few places and get error messages). I've got a copy of this code at the top - would you mind pointing out where you think it should be? Thanks for being so patient - Im pretty new to this!